# Set window-local option in every buffer/window

Tags: buffers, line-numbers

How do you set a window-local option (`number`) in literally every window/buffer?

I was to bind `<leader>t` to toggle the `number` option in every buffer, using a global variable `g:linum_status` as the source of truth for whether line numbers should be active or not.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to make `number` act like a global option, even though it's window-local.

I have the following options set initially

```
let g:linum_status = 0
set nonumber
```

and had the following (broken) function `ToggleLinum`

```
function! ToggleLinum()
  if g:linum_status
    bufdo execute "set nonumber"
    let g:linum_status = 0
  else
    bufdo execute "set number"
    let g:linum_status = 1
  endif
endfunction
```

This function, however, only toggles the `number` option in the current buffer.

I tried switching `bufdo` to `windo`, which is a little better. Now all of the windows in the focused tab switch, which is actually fairly intuitive.

Still though, is there a way to make flip `number` on or off for "every" buffer, possibly exempting things like netrw file exploring buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>t :<c-u>call ToggleLinum()<cr>

function! ToggleLinum() abort
    let orig_win = win_getid()
    let ft_to_ignore = ['netrw']
    if &l:number
        tabdo windo if index(ft_to_ignore, &ft) < 0 | setl nonumber | endif
    else
        tabdo windo if index(ft_to_ignore, &ft) < 0 | setl number | endif
    endif
    call win_gotoid(orig_win)
endfunction
```

It uses `:tabdo` to iterate over the tab pages, and `:windo` to iterate over the windows in each of them.

If, in addition to `netrw`, you wanted to ignore other filetypes, you could add them to the list `ft_to_ignore`. For example, to also ignore quickfix windows:

```
let ft_to_ignore = ['netrw', 'qf']
```

The function decides whether it should enable or disable `'number'` in all windows based on the value of this option in the current window (`&l:number`).

Since `:tabdo` and `:windo` will change the focused window (it will become the last window in the last tab page) you can use `win_getid()` to save the unique ID of the original window, and `win_gotoid()` to get back to it, once the function has finished toggling `'number'` everywhere.

---

> You can nest windo inside tabdo? What kind of thing are they
>   syntactically?

Honestly, I don't know what is the correct term for these keywords. But I can try to help you understand why it makes sense to nest them. From `:h :tabdo`:

```
It works like doing this:
        :tabfirst
        :{cmd}
        :tabnext
        :{cmd}
        etc.
```

Then, from `:h :windo`:

```
It works like doing this:
        CTRL-W t
        :{cmd}
        CTRL-W w
        :{cmd}
        etc.
```

In the first snippet of code, the one given in `:h :tabdo`, replace `{cmd}` with the 2nd snippet of code (increasing the level of indentation to better see the 2 different levels of nesting); it should give you the following pseudo-code, which still looks valid:

```
:tabfirst
    CTRL-W t
    :{cmd}
    CTRL-W w
    :{cmd}
    etc.
:tabnext
    CTRL-W t
    :{cmd}
    CTRL-W w
    :{cmd}
    etc.
etc.
```

FWIW, the way I see `tabdo` and `windo`, is like tab triggers in [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/423f264e753cec260b4f14455126e6db7ba429af/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L645). That is, they are expanded into snippets of code. In the help, `{cmd}` is a placeholder which, in the snippet, will be replaced with the command (or here another snippet) you pass to `:tabdo`/`:windo` as an argument.

Comment: Wow. You can nest `windo` inside `tabdo`? What kind of thing are they syntactically?